# How to Delete rows in database based on Username in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to delete few rows by Username. But my sql query apparently not working right. instead of reading the column username, it looks for the name as a column...

Edit: What im trying to achieve is to remove rows with the username John Rose... but insead it says its looking for the column name John Rose

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Jack Rose'.'

This code is in the checkout button. Im showing the whole code just incase the cause might be outide of the delete query code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            con.Open();
            string query = "INSERT INTO GuestOrder (Order_Id, Username, Order_Date, GrandTotal) values (@Order_Id, @Username, @Order_Date, @GrandTotal)";



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Id", Label_OrderId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Date", Label_OrderDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrandTotal", Label_Grand.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            string sql = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username =" + Username+"";

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM GuestOrder";
            SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("orderdetails");
            dt.Fill(ds, "order");
            ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath(@".\xml\orders.xml"));

            Response.Redirect("SuccessfulOrder.aspx");

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: your delete is wrong, i think it is a typo? `"DELETE from Cart WHERE Username =" + Username+"";`

Comment: @GabrielLlorico Omg... embarrassing....

Comment: also please use command parameters for this. What will happen if `Username` is `John Doe; DROP TABLE Cart` ?

Comment: What im trying to achieve is to remove rows with the username John Rose... but insead it says its looking for the column name John Rose...

Comment: @vasily.sib isnt DROP TABLE removed the whole database? i just want to delete some rows based on the Username session...

Comment: Try this. "DELETE from Cart WHERE Username ='" + Username+"'". I think the name should be within single quote.

Comment: @Rob Webs don't use `DROP` as it is used to delete the Table or Database.

Comment: @RobWebs, I mean that simple string concatination (like `"DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username =" + Username + "";` or `"DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username ='" + Username + "'"`) is vulnerable for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should **NEVER** concatenate SQL commands from user input. Use `cmd1.Parameters` for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put `username` in single quotes as below

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username = '" + Username+"'";
```

or You can use `parameterized` version of this query to avoid the `sql injection` as 
below:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username = @Username";
```

Comment: this code is vulnerable for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: First the code should work security comes next. He's well aware of this that's why he already used the parameterized queries. Now it's upto him if he uses parameterized version of this query.

Comment: I agree, but if some one will find this question through search - they can just copy-paste your answer without reading comments and miss the important part about possible vulnerability that comes with you code. So it will be nice if you warn everyone about this in your answer.

Comment: If someone finds this question and answer then it's his problem to read information completely. All are not same.

Comment: https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom

Answer (score 0):

You should use this as below:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Username = @Username";
```